# how to do special join on table A and B (keep A row and add B columns only when there is one on one match)

Tags: sql, join

I want to add to table A informations in table B only for the rows of table A having one and only one row match in table B.

Example :
GIVEN  table A

```
+ lastName firstName
+ A        B
+ C        D
+ E        F
```

AND table B

```
* lastName firstName age
* A        B         10
* C        D         15
* C        D         20
```

I WANT TABLE RESULT

```
* lastName firstName age
* A        B         10
* C        D         null
* E        F         null
```

Is it possible to do it in SQL? left join is not sufficient

Comment: It is possible. Do a GROUP BY on table B before the left join.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Comment: Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. What parts are you able to do? Where are you stuck? What did your textbook or the documentation say about anything relevant? (Except--this is a duplicate.)

Comment: @loic_midy . . . Your description and your data do not match.  Why is E/F added into B?  What happens to the ages?

Answer (score 2):

Kind of

```
select A.lastName, A.firstName, u.age
from A
left join (
   select lastName, firstName, max(age) age
   from B
   group by lastName, firstName
   having count(*) = 1 -- or may be count(distinct age) = 1
) u on u.lastName = A.lastName and u.firstName = A.firstName
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add unique rows in `B` to `A`.  For this, I would suggest `UNION ALL`:

```
select firstname, lastname, max(age) as age
from b
group by firstname, lastname
having count(*) = 1
union all
select firstname, lastname, null as age
from a
where not exists (select 1
                  from from b
                  group by firstname, lastname
                  having count(*) = 1
                 );
```

This should, at least, produce the results in your question.